# Set E with characteristic/indicator function having one sided limits at every point.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am teaching myself analysis via self study of the following book online:

http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf

Here is the question:

1. Give an example of a set $E$ such that the characteristic function $\chi_E$ of E has on-sided limits at every point. Can you describe the most general set E with this property?

I am a bit confused by the following question (Image posted). Clearly, any interval would qualify as an example. However, in all the cases we have both limits (left/right) at every internal point of the set. I do not see how you can have only one sided limits at every internal point without the function having both limits (left/right). Clearly, if it has a one sided limit at $x_o$ then there is an interval $(x_o, x_o + \delta)$ or $(x_o - \delta, x_o)$  for ever $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|\chi(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for every $x \in (x_o, x_o + \delta) | (x_o - \delta, x_o)$. This would mean there is a $c \in (x_o, x_o + \delta) | (x_o - \delta, x_o)$ where the limit exists on both sides
. This is true since L can take one of two values $\{0, 1\}$ and a point either belongs to the set or it does not belong to the set. Is the proof sufficient to show that all internal points of $E$ have both limits?

[image: TBB Question on Characteristic Function]

Comment: Please post a link to a smaller file. I don't feel like waiting for the one you link to loading...

Comment: @coffeemath I typed in the question. It is also attached as am image file.

Comment: What I meant was the image file you attached was (to me) to long when loading.

Comment: @coffeemath the image is 14KB. That is causing it to load slow?

Comment: The characteristic function of $[0,1]$ has both one-sided limits at each point, but fails to have a two-sided limit at either of the endpoints. For more variety, note that any finite union of intervals (open, closed, half-open, or a single point) has both one-sided limits at each point.

Comment: @Dave,  Thank you for you response. You have confirmed my understanding. The question was are there points other than end points where only one sided limits are possible? For which my answer was no.

Comment: @Dave I have modified my question to more accurately reflect what I was trying to say as opposed to a convoluted statement.